# How much time to update the Structured data in Search Results?

Tags: google-search-console, rdfa, structured-data

We have updated the structured data for the ratings in the website and it is detected also by the crawler but I am not able to view the ratings in the search results page.

I can see the breadcrumb results in the search results and can not see the other structured data in search results.

Do let us know if there is any issue which needs to be resolved from our end.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Google does not have enough computing power and indexing/freshening varies**

There are [over 50 billion pages indexed (Tuesday, 19 February, 2013)](http://www.worldwidewebsize.com/), Google does not have enough computing power to quickly update all pages/sites that get updated on the internet.

Google prioritizes crawling and updates times vary depending on how much importance/authority they believe your site has. If your site regularly freshens its pages then it should be fairly quickly. However if your pages have been untouched for months and years then it will take some time, but again this varies from site to site.

Google tends to learn how often your site gets updated and also monitors if pages get freshened so repeating myself a little here, it varies on many factors but the more you update your site the more often Google returns but just because Google returns doesn't mean it accesses those pages because it knows that say page about Cats hasn't been updated in 9months then its likely to ignore this page for a while. However if this page is constantly changing then it will return to that page and update much quicker.

**Test your Structured and then its a waiting Game**

I assume that you have tested your [structured data using the Google tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) if they are all fine then it's just a matter of waiting. It could take days, weeks or months it really depends on the volume of URLS you have and also how Google reviews your site like I said.

**Speeding up the process... Maybe...**

Sometimes you can force Google's hand in the speed of updating pages by creating some back links. For me personally I've had great success using social media and find my pages being updated much faster when I tweet, share, digg it, and reddit. But Google needs to find the new back link and then has to follow the link and this isn't always assured.

If you have any important pages then you can use social media platforms to encoverage Google to return to those pages quicker, don't go overboard but this is one method.

Comment: "Fetch as Google" page in Google Webmaster Tools can also be used to hint Google Bot about recrawling the submitted page, right?